# How to set a new kotlin and gradle version in React Native?

Tags: react-native, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have to use a lib called watermelondb, and, to use that, I have to get at least the 1.3.5 kotlin version, and my current version is 1.3.21, and when I try to set 1.3.5 I get an error that says:

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'espeleoapp'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5.pom
Required by:
    project :Java(0)
```

My build.gradle buildcript is like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        supportLibVersion = "30.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

and my gradle-wrapper.properties is like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

what do I have to change to get the correct kotlin version?

I tried to use differents versions, but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having similar issues just Yesterday. This might help.

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    kotlinVersion = "1.5.31"
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
    classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0")
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Rajwant Kaur Boughan, unfortunately it didn't work yet, in your gradle-wrapper.properties witch gradle -all.zip did you set?

Comment: @BrunoSiqueira Actuall it's an old project that I have to run in latest Android Studio version. distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip

Comment: I tried here setting gradle 6.9 but for some reason it's not working yet, do you think that could be some android studio config? did you change something there? @Rajwant Kaur Boughan

Comment: @BrunoSiqueira Can you describe what's going wrong after making these changes? I had to make some more changes also but it completely depends on each project's configuration.

Comment: Hi @Rajwant Kaur Boughan, thank you, I tried one more time, and now it worked, thank you so much for your support man.